# Docker gitlab container heatly but not accessible

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, docker-machine, owncloud

---

Hello,
I have the following problem on docker 18.06.1-ce.
I have an owncloud container that works with the following configurations:

- Image : owncloud/server:10.0
- Status healthy
- Ports : 0.0.0.0:4090->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4093->443/tcp

So far, so good, this container is functional.

Now, I want to add a gitlab container with the following configurations:

- Image : gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
- Status : heatly
- Ports : 0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4443->443/tcp

The problem is that I can't access the containers with the ports listed above (connection failed).
I tried to install the container in a different way:

- By docker run command :

`docker run --detach     --hostname nsXXXXX.ip-XX-XXX-XX.eu     --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'https://nsXXXXX.ip-XX-XXX-XX.eu:4443'; gitlab_rails['lfs_enabled'] = true;"     --publish 4443:443 --publish 8080:80 --publish 2222:22     --name gitlab     --restart always     --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab     --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab     --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab     gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest`

- And by docker-compose:

  `web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'nsXXXXXXX.ip-XX-XXX-XX.eu'
    privileged: true
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://nsXXXXXXX.ip-XX-XXX-XX.eu:4443/'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 4182
    ports:
      - '4180:80'
      - '4443:443'
      - '4182:22'
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'`

My docker is on a dedicated Debain Stretch hosted by kimsufi.

Do you have any ideas to help me? Thank you very much.

---

Comment: Is the gitlab container actually running? Can you connect directly to the open ports on the container's ip address?

Comment: Exactly, I can't know... The ip of the container is the one of the server. And when I try to access it I have a denied connection. While my owncloud container is working properly. Example : `https://MyServerIP.eu:4443/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved : https://forum.gitlab.com/t/docker-gitlab-container-healthy-but-not-accessible/20042/5

It was necessary to map the port of the external URL to the internal port... Beginner's error:)